# How can I avoid reloading the whole table, disrupting the scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to cap the number of elements to three. When I add element four, element one should disappear.

If I want scrolling to continue fine, I should tell `UITableView` that I am deleting rows in the entire `section` zero by calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. After that I need to tell `UITableView` that you are inserting a bunch of rows at the third `section` (section index 2).

This way you would be able to avoid reloading the whole table, disrupting the scroll.

But unfortunately it is not working for me.

Give me this error :

```
'attempt to delete row 3 from section 2, but there are only 1 sections before the update'
```

code :

```
    //scrolling down time calling this method
    func oldestState(){
        //var students : [[Student]]? = [[],[],[]]
        let data = getdata()
        self.students?[(self.firstIndex+self.count) % (self.students?.count)!] = data
        if (self.count != 3) {
            self.count += 1
        } else {
            self.firstIndex = (self.firstIndex+1) % (self.students?.count)!
        }

        self.newsFeedTableView.beginUpdates()
        let indexPathsDeleted = (0..<(data
            .count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: (self.students?.count)! - 1) }
        self.newsFeedTableView.deleteSections([0], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsDeleted, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.endUpdates()

        self.newsFeedTableView.beginUpdates()
        let indexPathsInsert = (0..<(data
.count)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: (self.students?.count)! - 1) }
        self.newsFeedTableView.insertSections([2], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsInsert, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        self.newsFeedTableView.endUpdates()
    }


    func getdata() -> [Student]{

        var _students = [Student]()
        for i in  itemNumber..<(itemNumber + 4) {
            let student = Student()
            student.name = "\(i)"
             print("adding student roll number : \(student.name)")
            _students.append(student)
        }
        itemNumber  +=  4
        return _students
    }
}
```

[Here is full Git code :](https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3/blob/master/PagginationSwift3/ViewController.swift)

Comment: If you have only 3 rows maximum, then just reload the whole table. It'll be easier to understand the code, and it's *highly* unlikely that you'll ever need to optimize it.

Comment: @NRitH I need to 3 section maximum and each section holding number of row based on api response item

Comment: @NRitH each request return 20 post or more and it will able append a section so when user scrolling and user goes to middle of the section then call web request and insert a section . when section reach 3 then 4 the request inserted section and remove from top section to the table view . is it make sense? would you help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the dataSource of the tableview behave,but from the error,it tells us clearly,that you have only one section,so you can't handle the section 2,because there isn't section 2.You can only handle the section 0.
You can delete the whole rows,and add row in section 0.besides,You should handle the self.students array,let it match the tableview rows,or it will crash.

**UPDATE:**

This commit resolve the issue **Table scrolling**

[I have correct it,This version.](https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3/commit/ccccd63bb1d5272854d47552c1540d5da40516db)

This commit resolve the issue **Table scrolling get jerky**

[I have correct it,This version.](https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3/commit/3fcc7ce4314ee14a087c69cf0cc48c9b74695bee)

Comment: full source code here https://github.com/nazmulkp/PagginationSwift3/blob/master/PagginationSwift3/ViewController.swift would you check please from there

Comment: i have read the code,there is only on section,the first call the initUpdateUI,the count property is 1.So the section is 1.

Comment: would you help me to fix that . what should I do . I spend al most 10 days . please

Comment: yeah,I can help you,but I want to know what do you want it be,there are 3 rows in section 0,and srcoll,what do you want?

Comment: The initial feed will download with 4 post for previewing, but if the user scrolling down then load more posts, so i need to add section to the bottom table view and section remove from the top. but tableview maximum 3 section hold. 1st time download then load section one . 2nd time download and load section two . 3rd time download load section 3 . now 4th time download load section 3 and remove section one from 1st.

Comment: you should know that the tableview's section is manage by the dataSource,if you should add or delete section, the students array should do the same activity.And when the you do the 4th download,you don't need to add section or delete,because there can't have section from 1 to 3,the system will auto change the section 1 to section 0.As it stands,you can call reloadData(),it is simply,and you just need to change the datasource.I will help you change the source code,wait a moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151013/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-zacks).

Comment: I check it is working fine but table scrolling get jerky
would you help me please how can I resolve the issue
http://i.imgur.com/CKZMDK6.gifv

Comment: you can try change the animation to none.

Comment: I did but no luck for me . Please help me

Comment: when there are 3sections,we delete first and add a new is wasty.so we can reloaddata() when count is 3.

Comment: would you  trying  it please . I tried but not working